# How to bind data from HttpClient in angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm using this method to get the data:

**home.service.ts**

```
getHomes(): Observable<HomeApi> {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'token': `${this.global.token}`
        })
    };
    return this.http.get<HomeApi>('url', httpOptions);
}
```

**home.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getHomes().subscribe((res: HomeApi) => this.home = {
        images: res['images']
    });
}
```

**home.component.html**

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of home.images">{{item.name}}</div>
```

Now `item.name` work great, but in console throws this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined

Here is the [Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqcjsv)

Comment: it seems that you are receiving back a malformed or an undefined response. what do you receive?

Comment: Can you do `console.log(res)` and check what is being returned?

Comment: Response is ok, becuase it's printing the data using ngFor

Comment: add if statement inside the {} to avoid the undefined values . for example, this.home = {
       if (res['images']) images: res['images']
    }

Comment: Hi, Could you please tell us how you have instantiated home, so that we can help you further? Also please check if the field is not private.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `getHomes` call is *asynchronous*, Angular attempts to render the contents of `home.images` before it has been assigned. After this happens, `home.images` gets assigned in your code and triggers a change-detection cycle that ends up with your `*ngFor` running successfully.

One way to handle this is to use something like the following:

```html
<div *ngIf="home">
    <div *ngFor="let item of home.images">{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

This simply ensures that `home` is not `undefined` before attempting to process the `*ngFor`, which will resolve your console error.

Another option is to use the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator):

> The Angular safe navigation operator (?.) is a fluent and convenient way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths.

This is as simple as adding a `?` to `home`:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of home?.images">{{item.name}}</div>
```

Comment: If you make the change I suggested in my answer, your sample works without errors. Have you tried it?

Comment: in my real project dos not work but in stackBlitz it's working. the console is now without errors but not showing anything

Answer (score 1):

You have probably not initialized `home`. So the first time you initialize home is here:

```
this.home = {
        images: res['images']
    }
```

Until then `*ngFor` looks for items in `home` object which is `undefined` until the asynchronous request is completed and `home` is initialized.

Try to initialize home on top of your component:
e.g. `home: any = {};`

[Check this piece, which demonstrates what it is probably happening.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6vttpt)

Comment: I'm using interface as type for home variable, still throws undefined

Comment: By using interface you are just defining the type of home - you still don't initialize it. You have to do something like `home: HomeApi = { sliders: [] }` on top of your component.